# Does Dwolla's payment button return an oAuth token?

Tags: payment, dwolla

Does Dwolla's payment button return an oAuth token which can be used such that the user never again has to redirect to Dwolla's website?

Comment: Please stop creating the `dwolla-api` tag.  We already have a tag here for Dwolla, we do not need another.

Comment: @Charles, sorry, fair point, thought it could be useful since other SAAS have done that but maybe Dwolla's service is not at this point yet (or the other services don't really need it either?),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paraphrasing from Dwolla technical support,

> "... the payment button uses the offsite gateway... which doesn't deal with oauth and/or tokens at all
>   plus, if you're gonna be using oauth tokens, you need a minimum level of coding knowledge anyway and the payment button was really just intended for those who dont code at all"